# Icon unwantedly changing input field size jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an input field.When a user inputs a text that is in `emoji` array,it gives the elements an icons class from an external stylesheet...just like emoji's.
All is well except

1. When the icon is shown, the name of the icon is shown on top of it
2. The icon changes the size of the input field..

I don't want any of that.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.inArray demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    color: blue;
  }
  span {
    color: red;
  }

  .em{
  font-color:white;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <link href="emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
 <div class ="see"></div>
<code>HEY</code>
 <input class="input">
 <div class ="see"></div>
  <div class ="see2"></div>
    <div class ="see3"></div>



<div class="add"></div>



<script>
var emojiss = [ "--abc", "--woman","--eye"];
var emoji=["-angel","-alien","----1","---1","--100","--1234","--8ball","--a","--ab","--abc","--abcd","--accept","--admission_tickets","--adult","--aerial_tramway","--airplane","--airplane_arriving","--airplane_departure"]

var input=$(".input");
var input2=$(".input").val();



 $(input).change(function(){

$(".see").html( $(".input").val());


if(jQuery.inArray($(".input").val(), emoji) != -1) {

var see=$(".see").html().replace('--', '').replace('--', '');


$(".see2").html(see);

var classs =see+"";

alert($(".see").html());




<!-- $(".see3").html(real); -->


    $(this).addClass("em em"+$(".see").html()).removeClass("see");

} else {
    alert("is NOT in array");


} 

});






</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because of the class `em` you're adding in :

```
$(this).addClass("em em" + $(".see").html()).removeClass("see");
__________________^^
```

You could see in the `emoji.css` that you're including the class rules are :

```
.em {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```js
var emojiss = ["--abc", "--woman", "--eye"];
var emoji = ["-angel", "-alien", "----1", "---1", "--100", "--1234", "--8ball", "--a", "--ab", "--abc", "--abcd", "--accept", "--admission_tickets", "--adult", "--aerial_tramway", "--airplane", "--airplane_arriving", "--airplane_departure"];
var input = $(".input");
var input2 = $(".input").val();


$(input).on('blur', function() {
  var selected_value = $(this).val();

  if ($.inArray(selected_value, emoji) !== -1) {
    $(".see").html('<i class="em em' + selected_value + '"></i>');
  } else {
    alert("is NOT in array");
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  color: blue;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<code>HEY type "-angel" for example in the input then blur the focus</code>
<br><br>
<input class="input">
<br><br>
<div class="see"></div>
<div class="add"></div>
```

Comment: Oh so what do I do

Comment: Why you're adding the class ?

Comment: What attribut Of the class should i change?

Comment: There's a bit of  a problem,those attributes ARENT present

Comment: ARENT present where ? in the css file ?

Comment: It is not in the css file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179649/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-titox-d-boss).

Comment: And what about the fact that the name is shown on top?